# Testing a secured webservivce in SOAP UI

Tags: web-services, security, axis, soapui

I am using AXIS2 framework for my webservices creating. Now I am secured my webservices using ramprt. Now entire requests and response will be signed and encrypted.

Now my doubt is how can i test it in SOAP UI. when I am loading wsdl file it giving me as 
below.

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soapenvelope"
       xmlns:sam="http://sample03.policy.samples.rampart.apache.org">
    <soap:Header/>
     <soap:Body>
        <sam:echo>
              <!--Optional:-->
              <sam:args0>?</sam:args0>
        </sam:echo>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Now Ho w can i place digital certificate related data and how can i encrypt the content i want to send to axis server.

Thanks,
Narendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the certificate data is stored in two xml Files the Outflowsecurity.xml and Inflowsecurity.xml they should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="action">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Outflow security 'action' configuration</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="items" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="user" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="passwordCallbackClass" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="signaturePropFile" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="encryptionPropFile" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="encryptionPropFile" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="signatureKeyIdentifier" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="encryptionKeyIdentifier" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="encryptionUser" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="signatureParts" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>

            <xs:element name="encryptionParts" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="optimizeParts" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="encryptionSymAlgorithm" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="EmbeddedKeyCallbackClass" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="encryptionKeyTransportAlgorithm" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="EmbeddedKeyName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="timeToLive" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:element>
```

for more details go to [the Apache help Page](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/modules/rampart/1_0/security-module.html)

To use the authentification in the Request you need to add a Tag to the soap:Header

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security
        soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsu:Timestamp
            wsu:Id="Timestamp-31497899">
            <wsu:Created>2008-02-06T13:39:50.943Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2008-02-06T13:44:50.943Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:UsernameToken
            wsu:Id="UsernameToken-10697954">
            <wsse:Username>apache</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password
                Type="http://...#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

the namespaces are:

```
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
```

Comment: of course that is only the schema the actual xml has different elementnames

Comment: I found this Info on http://wso2.org/library/3190#With_security, so try looking there, if anything isn't clear. In fact you should only look there, it has a step by step instruction for working with Apache rampart. greez